# codeigniter update multiple record using checkbox with mongo

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

I'm using the checkbox to sending an email that already selected. after the email sent, the status sendinvoice change to Y. everything is fine when I select 1 checkbox. but **when I choose multiple checkboxes, the function only update 1 checkbox**

How to make it can run update function with multiple checkboxes?

the view code for checkbox and button below

```
<button type="button" class="btn waves-effect waves-light btn-info" id="btn-sentcitilink"> Sent Email</button>

<?php
       foreach($result as $row){
       ?>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>cms/emailcitilink" id="sentemailcitilink">
        <?php
       }
      ?>
            <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Send Invoice </th>
                        <th>Booking ID</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                                          foreach($result as $row){
                                            ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td>

                                <?php if($row['sendinvoice'] == 'N'){ ?>
                                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="books[]" id="tableDefaultCheck/<?php echo $row['booking_id']?>" value="<?php echo $row['booking_id']?>">
                                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="tableDefaultCheck/<?php echo $row['booking_id'] ?>"></label>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php } ?>

                                        <?php if($row['sendinvoice'] == 'Y'){ ?>
                                            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="tableDefaultCheck3" checked disabled>
                                                <label class="custom-control-label" for="tableDefaultCheck3"></label>
                                            </div>
                                            <?php } ?>

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="hover-link">
                                    <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>cms/transaction/view/<?php echo $row['_id'] ?>">
                                        <?php echo $row['booking_id'] ?>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                                          }
                                          ?>

                </tbody>
            </table>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {

                    $("#check-all").click(function() { 
                        if ($(this).is(":checked")) 
                            $(".check-item").prop("checked", true); 
                        else // Jika checkbox all tidak diceklis
                            $(".check-item").prop("checked", false); 
                    });

                    $("#btn-sentcitilink").click(function() { 
                        var confirm = window.confirm("Apakah Anda mengirim email data-data ini?"); 

                        if (confirm) 
                            $("#sentemailcitilink").submit(); 
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

The controller code

```
function emailtocitilink(){
        $books = $_POST['books'];
        $get_trans = $this->cms_model->get_transaction_by_list_trip($tripsData);

        foreach($get_trans as $row){

                    $arr_data = array(
                        'booking_id'                => $row['TRANSIDMERCHANT'],
                    );

                    array_push($arr, $arr_data);

        }
        $data = $this->data;
        $data['result'] = $arr;

        $datas = array(
            'SendINVOICE'     => "Y"
        );


        $insert = $this->cms_model->update_transaction($datas, $books);

        redirect(base_url().'cms/citilinktransaction/');

    }
```

Model

```
function get_transaction_by_list_trip($TripUUID){
    return $this->mongo_db
                        ->where_in('TripUUID', $TripUUID)
                        ->where(array('PAYMENTCHANNEL' => 'TESTINGCHANNEL'))
                          ->order_by(array('transaction_date' => 'desc'))
                          ->get('tr_transaction');
}

function update_transaction($datas, $books){
    return $this->mongo_db->where_in('TRANSIDMERCHANT', $books)
                          ->set($datas)
                          ->update('tr_transaction',['multi' => TRUE]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On model, it should be `'multiple' => true`

Answer (score 0):

Use `update_all` to update multiple records:

```php
$this->mongo_db
     ->set($datas, ["multi" => true])
     ->where_in('TRANSIDMERCHANT', $books)
     ->update_all('tr_transaction');
```